# Summary of disk usage for all databases using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

How can I see all disk usage of all my databases on a given SQL Server in one single query. I have around 15 different databases on my server and I want to see which one is using the maximum disk space.

I know I can see reports of Disk Usage per database in SSMS or logon to the server and see the size of MDF/LDF files but this seems like a pretty obvious feature that should come with SSMS and I cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built in way but you can use the (undocumented) `sp_MSforeachdb` procedure for this.

```
CREATE TABLE #files(
    [dbname] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [physical_name] [nvarchar](260) NOT NULL,
    [size] [int] NOT NULL,
    [max_size] [int] NOT NULL,
    [growth] [int] NOT NULL
)

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb ' 
insert into #files
select ''[?]'',name,physical_name,size,max_size,growth
from [?].sys.database_files'


SELECT [dbname]
      ,[name]
      ,[physical_name]
      ,[size]
      ,[max_size]
      ,[growth]
  FROM #files
```

Comment: sp_spaceused can also come in bandy with this now

Comment: Somehow the word management doesn't seem to belong with this product if it can't list disk space per database.

Comment: @NetMage See my answer--it can.

Comment: Your answer is great, but has nothing to do with SSMS.

Comment: @NetMage you can execute queries in SSMS! Just open a new query window and run it!

Comment: True. But that has nothing to do with SSMS as a management tool.

Comment: @NetMage well SSMS doesn't have any built in way to do it AFAIK so you're stuck rolling your own solution. Using its capability to execute queries seems a perfectly satisfactory answer to me.

Answer (score 10):

This stored procedure will help.

```
exec sp_helpdb;
```

You'll get something like this:

```
name      db_size       owner         dbid created     status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          compatibility_level
--------- ------------- ------------- ---- ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------- 
Database1    7262.81 MB DOMAIN\Admin  5    Aug 25 2010 Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=661, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics                                                                             100
Project27   22781.81 MB DOMAIN\User42 13   Oct 13 2011 Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=661, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsTornPageDetectionEnabled, IsAnsiNullsEnabled, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsQuotedIdentifiersEnabled 100
MyDBName       84.69 MB DOMAIN\Me     14   Oct 14 2011 Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=661, Collation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, SQLSortOrder=52, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsFullTextEnabled                                                          100
```

To learn more about a particular database, do:

```
exec sp_helpdb DatabaseName;
```

Comment: this worked great for me showing me the MB my database was using.